# Passing State between components in React

Tags: reactjs

This may be a pretty easy fix, but I'm a React noob and I can't quite figure it out. I have a SignIn component that keeps track of the state of a user when they log in. I want to pass this state over to a Dashboard component to present some user info.

**SignIn.js:**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import firebase from '../config/firebaseConfig'
import { Redirect } from 'react-router-dom'

import GoogleLoginButton from './GoogleLoginButton'

class SignIn extends Component {
  state = {
    email: '',
    password: '',
    user: null
  }

  handleChange = (e) => {
    this.setState({
      [e.target.id]: e.target.value
    })
  }

  signIn = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault()
    firebase.auth().signInWithEmailAndPassword(this.state.email, this.state.password)
      .then(user => {
        this.setState({
          user
        })
      })
      .catch(err => {
        console.log(err)
      })
  }

  signUp = () => {
    this.props.history.push('/signup')
  }

  render() {
    if (this.state.user) return <Redirect to='/' />
    return (
      <div className="container">
        <div>
          <form id="signIn">
            <div className="input-field">
              <label htmlFor="email">Email</label>
              <input type="email" id="email" onChange={this.handleChange} />
            </div>
            <div className="input-field">
              <label htmlFor="password">Password</label>
              <input type="password" id="password" onChange={this.handleChange} />
            </div>
            <div className="input-field">
              <button className="btn blue left" onClick={this.signIn}>Sign In</button>
            </div>
          </form>
          <div>
            <button className="btn blue right" onClick={this.signUp}>Sign Up</button>
          </div>
        </div>
        <br/><br/><br/>
        <div className="center">
          <GoogleLoginButton />
        </div>
      </div>
    )
  }
}

export default SignIn
```

**Dashboard.js:**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'

import SignOutButton from './SignOutButton'

class Dashboard extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="container center">
        <div>
          <SignOutButton />
        </div>
      </div>
    )
  }
}

export default Dashboard
```

What would be the best way to go about passing login state to the Dashboard component?

Answer (score 2):

For using current user you need to maintain in your state to use across application.

**Options to use**

1- Context api [docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html)

2- Redux [docs](https://redux.js.org/introduction/getting-started)

3- localStorage

Answer (score 0):

Like this:

```
<Redirect to={{
      pathname: '/',
      state: { id: 1 }
   }}
/>
```

Access from Dashboard:

```
this.props.location.state
```

You can also pass any data from a state in SignIN

```
<Redirect to={{
      pathname: '/',
      state: { email: this.state.email }
   }}
/>
```

[API DOC](https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/blob/master/packages/react-router/docs/api/Redirect.md#to-object)

Answer (score 0):

You can also do:

```
this.props.history.push("/", { response: YOUR_DATA }) FROM signin
```

and access it in your dashboard like:

```
const state = this.props.location.state
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest three ways of doing this.

1. **Parent Props**

   > no need of redux and context for this

wrap login form with a parent component and send a function as prop into loginForm component

```
<LoginForm setUser={user => this.setState({user})}/>
```

and use this state in parent component in another component like *Dashboard*

2. Context :

   > probably the best way
3. Redux :

   > if data is too large and need to access across numerous components

Answer (score 0):

You can use react router to pass data between different routes as follows.

```
this.props.router.push({
  pathname: '/newPage',
  state: {
    newValue: 123
  }
})
```

Or other way is using cookies or local storage

```
import Cookies from 'universal-cookie';
const cookies = new Cookies();

export const SESSION_USER_NAME = 'SESSION_USER_NAME';
cookies.set(SESSION_USER_NAME, userName);

and to get value from cookie 

cookies.get(SESSION_USER_NAME),
```